# Regex, replace group between other groups?

Tags: c#, regex

I have such a regex:

```
string ipPort = @"[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}[\s\S]*?[0-9]{1,5}";
Regex Rx = new Regex(ipPort,RegexOptions.Singleline);
List<string> catched = new List<string>();

foreach (Match ItemMatch in Rx.Matches(page))
{
    catched.Add(ItemMatch.ToString());
}
```

It will find ip, followed by any number of characters, followed by port number. I want this "any number of characters" replaced by single colon ":". How to do that, I'm not very experienced with regular expressions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this general expression that uses lookarounds in order to find a pattern between a prefix and a suffix:

```
(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)
```

Applied to your specific problem:

```
(?<=[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})[^0-9].*?(?=[0-9]{1,5})
```

Note that I have added a `[^0-9]` meaning "not a digit". There must be at least one non-digit character there, because otherwise the search cannot distinguish between digits belonging to the last ip-group and the port number.

You can also repeat the number-dot group three times and then append the fourth number

```
(?<=([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})[^0-9].*?(?=[0-9]{1,5})
```

You can also replace `[\s\S]` (space or non-space character) by `.` (any character).

Applied to our general expression, now we have:

prefix (ip): `([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}`
find (stuff to be replaced by colon): `[^0-9].*?`
suffix (port): `[0-9]{1,5}`